# What does "webster" mean?

Tags: meaning

I tried Lingvo Online but it does not give the answer, but says there is a translation in the paid version of the dictionary. I do not know whether other dictionaries do.

What is the meaning of the word "webster"?

Comment: Can you give us some context?

Comment: Yes, context please.  It could be an improperly capitalized person's name, it could be a poetic name for a spider (one who spins or weaves webs) or maybe for a person who uses the internet.  Or something else.

Comment: @Jim I am interested in the generic, non-modern meaning. Does it mean spider?

Comment: @Anixx- ***Please*** provide some context-  At a minimum the sentence you saw it in, and ideally any other surrounding sentences that provide additional *clues* to its usage as well as where you saw it.

Comment: @Anixx Jim's comment about spiders was a little joke. No, it doesn't mean spider. Let's make a deal: you tell us the longer sentence or passage you found *webster* in, and what made you come ask us what it means, and we'll tell you what it means, ok?

Comment: @Dan Bron I am just trying to figure out whether the webster to web is the same as gangster to gang and mobster to mob. Can I for other words with -ster?

Comment: @Anixx No. "Webster" is not in use in English as a generic noun; OED and Merriam-Webster (no pun intended) list it as an archaic term for "weaver," but it is not one which one would ever expect to hear.

Comment: Well, a mobster is one who is in the mob, and a gangster is one who is in a gang, but a webster is *not* one who is in a web.

Comment: @cpast thanks! So it means a weaver! This can be the answer.

Comment: @Jim there is also hipster!

Comment: @Anixx Jim is right. Webster is a proper name (including that of Daniel Webster, who founded a famous English dictionary, now Merriam-Webster). The suffix *-ster* is productive in English, and turns verbs (typically) into nouns of the form one-who-does-or-performs-*verb*, but the results of such novel coinings are typically [jocular](http://j.mp/1GfSumD) (ie humorous) and ephemeral: nonce words used once and thrown away. You would almost never use (novel) *-ster* words in a serious context, and in fact using *any* neologism when a formal register is called for is risky.

Comment: @Dan Bron is this suffix hative to English, comes from Latin -tor/-ter or from -er via Latin -arius?

Comment: @Anixx No. No no! *Webster* **does not** mean *weaver*. Webster *used to mean* weaver. Just like *demortuus* **used to** mean *obsolete*, but if you used it today, no one would have any idea what you're saying.

Comment: @DanBron W e l l . . . I'd know, and presumably you'd know, and some hundreds of thousands of other folks who'd run across the word. But in the big picture you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Webster" is listed in both the OED and Merriam-Webster online versions as an archaic term for a weaver (particularly a female one). Sources: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226715?rskey=1LkzdF&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid), [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/webster)

Answer (score 8):

*Webster* is not a widely used word in current English.

The most likely similar word you might see in general reading or conversation is *Webster's*, which is part of the title of several well-known dictionaries, and might be used generically to refer to any dictionary.

For example,

> Q: Do you know what *dicombobulate* means?
>
> A: No, let me get out my Webster's and find out.

Comment: I, for some reason, seem to use the word a little more regularly than others :P.